# User inserting items in a table

Tags: asp.net, linq, insert

I have created a simple web form on ASP.NET which includes a DropDownList with the names of all the records of a table (h. PhotoAlbums) in my database. When the user selects an album, all the items of this album (photos with tootlips) appear on the page in an order. I have carried out this by the aid of ListView control assigning a LINQ source as data source.

I would like by the selection of an album to grant the user the possibility to insert new items in the selected album at the same time and on the same page besides the appearance of the already existed items in the album. I think that I should merely use a DetailsView control and adjust this, so as to insert items. Is it though possible the DetailsView to appear after the selection of an album; not when the page is loaded initially? How?

Comment: can't you move to a `AddPicture.aspx` page, instead of a all-in-one page ?

Comment: That is attainable but I would like to know if it could work as I am desribing it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question,

You can Initially set the `visible = "false"` to the `DetailsView`. Then in your `DropDownList` [OnSelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.onselectedindexchanged.aspx) method you can check the selected value and set the `visible= "true"`. In your `DropDownList` you should set the property `AutoPostBack="true"`

Hope This Helps